# Boot directly on desktop instead of overview / dash / dock - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, dock

When starting a Gnome Shell session in Ubuntu 22.04, the session starts with the dash or dock in an active state. The Gnome Shell search has focus and Workspaces are visible.

[image: Gnome Shell with Dash active]

In previous versions of Ubuntu the session simply begins at the desktop.

[image: Gnome Shell with Desktop active]

How can I revert to the previous behaviour, so the dash is not active when I log in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In current versions of Gnome Shell, the initial screen after log in is the overview rather than the desktop. It takes an extension to revert to the classical behavior, where you are on the desktop after login.

In a default Ubuntu desktop, that option is provided by the Ubuntu Dock extension. Also the [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extension provides that option.

If you do not use any extension that includes that option, the Gnome Shell extension  [No overview at start-up](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4099/no-overview/) by fthx can provide this option.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thank you very much

Comment: For those who using "Dash to panel" extension like me : Go to settings > Behavior > and enable "Hide overview on startup"

Comment: Good to know. I will add this information to the answer for completeness!

Comment: The main question is open for review in the reopen vote review queue.